# Twitter iOS image search by hashtag

Tags: ios, search, twitter, hashtag

I need to search images from a certain hashtag in twitter to my iOS 6 app. I am trying to code a query that retrieves a minimal size possible response.
So, I tried to use Twitpic,  but the response is not good. it's outdated and incomplete. So, I went to the Twitter 1.0 API. The 1.1 is not good because it require user account in Twitter and a lot of my users don´t have it.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag%20pic.twitter.com&rpp=100&include_entities=true&result_type=recent

Does have a better way to query images from twitter api? I only need the image urls, not the entire entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Twitter and Instagram respond a big JSON, I decided to implement the logic in a server using PHP. My client send the hashtag and the server retrieve the image´s urls and send them this parameters and the next "page_id" from twitter and facebook.

It made the operation faster and more future friendly to my apps, besides avoid some "bad images".